# Failed to resolve endpoint: No component found with scheme: exec

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I am trying to invoke a simple shell script using Apache Camel but am getting the error:

`Failed to resolve endpoint: exec:///usr/local/karaf/data/tmp/test.sh due to: No component found with scheme: exec`

In my camel-context.xml I have

```
  <route id="common_route">
    <from uri="direct:common_route" />
    <to uri="exec:/usr/local/karaf/data/tmp/test.sh"/>
  </route>
```

And in my pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
   <artifactId>camel-exec</artifactId>
   <version>${camel.version}</version>
 </dependency>
```

We are using Camel version 2.15.3. And we are using Spring Camel. 
Any ideas? This is one of those things that must be so simple it is very frustrating.

Btw it makes no difference if I use
`exec:/usr/....`
or 
`exec:///usr/....`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The docs make no mention of this..at least, not on the camel exec page.

1: I had to add the line
`org.apache.camel.component.exec`
to my pom.xml in

```
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Spring-Context>*;create-asynchronously:=false</Spring-Context>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Import-Package>
                          ...
                          org.apache.camel.component.exec
                          ...
```

2: I had to run the following commands in the Karaf console:

```
bundle:install mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-exec/2.15.3
bundle:install mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-exec/1.3
bundle:install mvn:commons-io/commons-io/1.4
```